# Как добавить символ в файл после другого символа в Си

Tags: c

Доброго времени суток программисты и форумчане! Возникла небольшая проблема. Мой код должен дописать строку после каждого символа в цикле. То есть он перемещается на один символ относительно начала и дописывает эту строку после каждого символа пока не встретится EOF- конец файла. Однако когда я запускаю код он всегда все пишет в конец

Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Enter to filename or path:");

    char path[300];

    scanf("%300s" , path);

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(path , "r");

    if(fp == NULL) {

        printf("Sorry! This file inacesible or not found!\n");

        exit(1);
    
    }else{

        fclose(fp);

        fp = fopen(path , "a+");

        char ch;

        while((ch = fgetc(fp) != EOF)) {

            char string_1[300] = "3466367367";

            fseek(fp , 2 , SEEK_SET);
            
            fputs("parta" , fp);
        } 

        printf("File succesfully crypted!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Данные в файле хранятся **физически**. Вы не можете виртуально сказать байтам, быстро подвиньтесь. Всё нужно писать в **новый** файл. Открытие файла с опцией "a+" *(append)* не позволяет писать в середину файла, только в конец. Команда `fseek(fp , 2 , SEEK_SET);` переходит постоянно в одно место файла. Это ошибка.

Comment: Для сдвига относительно текущей позиции нужен `SEEK_CUR`, только все равно ничего не получится по уже указанным вам причинам. И еще — при открытии файла `a+`, т.е. для добавления, вы получаете *On the append file access modes, data is written to the end of the file regardless of the current position of the file position indicator.* (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) — перевод не требуется?...